# Remove existing CloudCode from an app

Tags: ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I set up CloudCode for my app using the instructions found in the [Parse documentation](https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#command-line-setting-up-your-app). Unfortunately I gave it a poor name and it is placed in an undesirable location. I would like to remove it and recreate it.

I have created a new CloudCode and moved the code into that. But I did create a Scheduled Job that uses a function in the CloudCode from the old location. Is there a special process I need to go through in order to get rid of the old CloudCode, or can I simply trash that directory and run `parse deploy` with the new CloudCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can trash the directory and run `parse deploy`. Parse's CLI overwrites the entire directory structure remotely using the local copy. Your instincts here are correct.